# LibGDX: Apply natural force from a falling object

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm working on an Android game containing LibGDX and I'm struggling with my physics.

I my game I want an object to start fall vertically(g = 9.82) on touch. Then I have a plate where I can perform a lifting/swing motion to apply new force to the object. Depending on the swing, the object should land a few tiles away on the goal (example in a bucket) to score.

How should I write the physics in the best/effecient and most natural way? How can I add all the combinded forces from the plate and object so the object can fly in the right angle with the right force? Should I use Box2d?

Note: The object is sligthly bendning from its form, meaning that it will drop inconsistent to the plate.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcZVU.png)

Comment: That question might be better suited to gamedev.stackexchange.com but I'd suggest using a physics engine. You don't want to model all the details yourself. With a proper physics engine you normally just need to bother with how you initialize movement/apply forces etc. (i.e. how the object starts moving, how the plate is moving) as well as some properties of the objects involved (mass, surface friction etc.).

Comment: Okay! Can you recommend a game engine who will suit my project?

Comment: I do highly recommend to you to use Box2d, because all of what you try to do, Box2d already doing.

Comment: I'd also recommend Box2d. I havent personally used it yet but it seems very stable, mature and supported by a large community.

Comment: Alright! Will checkbox2d out, thanks.